# A different number of scans to expand the C preprocessor macro

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, macros, preprocessor

such a question below is a simple macro, however, the compilation behavior of msvc and gnu / clang is different, so to expand macro A in msvc, you need 1 scan more than gnu / clang, why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER_(X) X EMPTY()
#define DEFER1(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER_(EMPTY)()
#define DEFER(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER_(EMPTY)()
#define TO_STR(X) TO_STR_(X)
#define TO_STR_(X) #X
#define A() 123
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EXPAND1(...) EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__)
int main(void)
{
 printf(TO_STR(EXPAND1(DEFER(A)()))"\n");
}
```

The behavior for all compilers presented on godbolt is the same as gnu except msvc.

Comment: Do you compile it as C or C++?

Comment: @mch as C, but the preprocessor is the same.

Comment: In MSVC, specify the [`/Zc:preprocessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor) compiler switch to invoke the C99 / C++11 conforming preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MSVC does not use standard C or C++ rules for preprocessing. Use the switch `/Zc:preprocessor` to [request standard-compliant preprocessing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/c-cpp-preprocessor-reference?view=msvc-170). You can also use `/std:c17` to request conformance to the C standard generally, not just in preprocessing, although conformance may not be complete.